# How to change the default page for a site in Sharepoint using Team Definition?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using the SharePoint extensions 1.1 for Visual Studio 2005 to deploy my website in SharePoint 2007. When you create a new site, there is a new default page with the ContenType: Welcomelinks.... I would like to change this to include my own ContentType and PageLayout in the onet.xml. I am deploying this using Team Definition.

Could someone give me some suggestions, please?

Comment: Do you have to use VSeWSS 1.1?

Comment: Yes, this is the way I have to use. I have added an element.xml with the ContentTypeBinding and i have modified the onet.xml and added it as a feature, and as a module. But I deploy the Team Definition the feature it creates appears with the title "Untitled". Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try applying your module to the **onet.xml** file?

in

```
<Project...>
  <Configurations...>
    <configuration...>
      <Modules>
```

Create a module element:

```
<Module Name="Default"/>
```

Then in

```
<Project..>
  <Modules>
```

have something like this for the definition:

```
<Module Name="Default" Url="" Path="">
    <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True">
    </File>
</Module>
```

I think that will at least put you on the right track.  I hope.